# keras fit performance - single GPU parallelism not working

Tags: tensorflow, keras, parallel-processing

I have a single-GPU system with CUDA and tensorflow-gpu all setup and running. I am running the simple Open AI Cartpole problem, as many people can relate to it and I verified with task manager that the CPU cores are not used, but the GPU is actually doing the calculations in the intense experience replay:

```
Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
...
Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3012 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 960...
```

In the Keras documentation, it says that a single-CPU or single-GPU system automatically does parallelization for the forward and backward passes, and the data generation can be parallelized also, with a custom generator.

However, my issue is with the suggested automatic parallelization that is supposed to happen. The line

```
self.model.fit(np.asarray(current_states), np.asarray(q_values),batch_size=self.batch_size,verbose=0)
```

requires linearly more time, depending on the batch_size. Emprically tested, 32 batches requires 2,1 to 2,5 seconds whereas 128 batches require 9 to 10 seconds (4 times as long).
My GPU is never exceeding 10% workload though! That means, my GPU is bored to death and the execution could be tons of times faster, if it were used properly.

I am not looking to distribute my model among several devices, but I would like to know why my single-GPU system is not using the GPU to its full potential? If the GPU consupmtion is not running at 100%, adding more batches during the `model.fit()` call should not increase the runtime, but simply run those batches in parallel to all the others.

What is it that is not working here?

Comment: Your results only show that the GPU is not the bottleneck, other things could be the bottleneck, like data transfer between CPU/GPU, or data generation in the CPU. It is hard to say with little information that you have given.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Do you have a recommendation how to measure other potential bottlenecks? Once I have further infos, I can update them here to consolidate the picture of what may be wrong.